# 301 redirect htaccess for sitecore items

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, sitecore

I have a url "http://www.abc.edu/test/program"
now I need to add "/" to this .Here program is the Sitecore Item.

If I type program in the google, I am getting two duplicates urls

One is with "/" and other is without "/" 
both are same.

I need to do it in the htaccess file,Can I get steps for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your `test/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^(program)$ $1/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Can I do it on IIS

Comment: This is Apache specific. IIS rewrite module has different syntax.